# Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') after Upgrading .NET 5 to .NET 7

Tags: .net, postgresql

I have upgraded my API to be working with .NET 7 and Ubuntu 23.04, everything went fine, the API and database are connected on my local machine and I can send request, but when I publish and deploy the app to my server, it seems that it doesn't read the `connectionString` in `appsetting.json` .

Here is my `appsettings.json`

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Secret": "*************",
        "EmailFrom": "********",
        "SmtpHost": "v******",
        "SmtpPort": 587,
        "SmtpUser": "a*****",
        "SmtpPass": "HJu******"
    },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WebApiDatabase": "Data Source=WebApiDatabase.db",
    "HangfireConnection": "Server=**.**.***.***;Port=5432;Database=Min;User Id=postgres;Password=min***;" //server
    //"HangfireConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Min;User Id=postgres;Password=*****;" // local
  },

    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "Hangfire": "Information"
      } 
    },

    "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "postgresqlconnection": {
    "connectionString": "Server=**.**.***.***;Port=5432;Database=Min;User Id=postgres;Password=min***;" //server
    //"connectionString": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Min;User Id=postgres;Password=*****;" // local
  },

    "mongoconnection": {
        "connectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass%20Community&ssl=false",
        "database": "backlog",
        "collection": "rawData",
        "collectionpMedian": "resultPmedian",
        "collectionClustering": "resultClustering"
    },

    "urlSettings": {
        "staticPageUrl": "http://**.**.***.***",
        "backendUrl": "http://**.**.***.***"
    },

    "variousSettings": {
        "defaultMessage": "A default message if nothing is found in the database."
    }
}
```

My `startup.cs`

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                .UsePostgreSqlStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection")));
```

My `DataContext.cs`

```
private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            // connect to postgress database
            var connectionString = Configuration["postgresqlconnection:connectionString"];

            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        }
```

`The error`

```
root@ubuntu-4gb:/# /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/MinAPI/MinWebApi.dll
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlStorage..ctor(String connectionString, Action`1 connectionSetup, PostgreSqlStorageOptions options)
   at Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlBootstrapperConfigurationExtensions.UsePostgreSqlStorage(IGlobalConfiguration configuration, String connectionString, Action`1 connectionSetup, PostgreSqlStorageOptions options)
   at Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlBootstrapperConfigurationExtensions.UsePostgreSqlStorage(IGlobalConfiguration configuration, String connectionString)
   at WebApi.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_2(IGlobalConfiguration configuration) in D:\C Sharp\Startup.cs:line 46
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<AddHangfire>b__0(IServiceProvider provider, IGlobalConfiguration config)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddHangfire>b__14(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.ThrowIfNotConfigured(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateBackgroundJobServerHostedService(IServiceProvider provider, JobStorage storage, IEnumerable`1 additionalProcesses, BackgroundJobServerOptions options)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<AddHangfireServerInner>b__0(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitNoCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\C Sharp\Program.cs:line 12
```

I have tried to hardcode the string inside the functions but the same error happens, tried to change variable name the same, tried to update the `appsettings.Development.json` to be the same as `appsetting.json`, it worked but when I restart the app service the error appears again.

Please guide me.

Comment: `var connectionString = Configuration["postgresqlconnection"]["connectionString"];` maybe? Or why not use the normal `Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection")` instead? Also `SetDataCompatibilityLevel` is weird as you are using Postgres not SQL Server

Comment: No, not gone to work. I have tried it. The problem is that it works fine on my laptop but when I deploy it, it doesn't work because of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error kept appearing every time I update the API on the server, however I found that editing the `appsettings.json` within the server solves the problem for that time only, and I need to do that every time, however, It can be ignored as the API works perfeclty fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please verify that your Appsettings file is actually being published?
Also Appsettings.Development.Json is only read when running locally in an IDE(Visual Studios, ETC). Otherwise it will try and read Appsettings.Json or Appsettings.Production.Json

Comment: Yes, it's published with all the other files, but not sure why it doesn't read it.

Comment: Will you please go out to the server where the files are located and copy the contents of the appsettings file. and include them.

Comment: I have updated the question with the `appsetting` file content.